# After changing store for different language it does not change static content or user added content in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2

I have created 2 store views one for English and another for Persian and it works,but when I change website language, it converts only Magento phrases,

Actually, I want to convert all additional information,
I tried using the language dictionary 'fa_IR.csv'(Persian dictionary) but that also affects only Magento prases.

How can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate static blocks/cms-pages for each English and Persian store view.

```
Cms pages will show when we change store view.
```

Now, you can use below syntax to get store wise static blocks in phtml (template) file.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block-english')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block-persian')->toHtml();?>
```

Where **block-english** and **block-persian** are your block identifiers.

**NOTE: Only 1 block will show to frontend depending upon store selection.**

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Create all static block separately for Persian storeview and then assign to Persian store.
 Also use below syntax for put static title in phtml file.

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('your text here') ?>
```